# Show $\frac{1}{\lvert a - b \rvert} < \frac{2}{\lvert a \rvert}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, absolute-value

I am tasked with the following:

> Show the following inequality for $\lvert b \rvert < \frac{\lvert a \rvert}{2}$ where $a,b \in \Bbb R$:
> $$\frac{1}{\lvert a - b \rvert} < \frac{2}{\lvert a \rvert}$$

I'm a bit at a loss as to where to even start with this one. I'm mostly looking for a little nudge.

Comment: [Avoid “no clue” questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969)

Comment: @MartinR Noted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$|a-b|>\left||a|-|b|\right| \ge |a|-|b| >|a|-|a|/2=|a|/2$.
Take the inverse of both sides, and you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract $|a|$ from both sides and use $|x| = |x+y-y| < |x+y|+|y|$, so that  $|x|-|y| < |x+y|$

Answer (score 0):

WLOG assume $a>0$ then $|b|<\frac{a}{2}$
$$
\frac{1}{|a-b|} = \frac{1}{a-b}<\frac{1}{a-\frac{a}{2}}=\frac 2a=\frac{2}{|a|}.\blacksquare
$$