# $\min(a,b+c)\leq \min(a,b)+ \min(a,c)$ for $a,b,c\geq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given $a,b,c\geq 0$, then this following is true
$$\min(a,b+c)\leq \min(a,b)+ \min(a,c)$$

I tried to prove it by using some cases, i.e.
Case 1: if $\,\,a\leq b \leq c\,\,$ and $\,\,a\leq c \leq b,\,\,$ it's clear that
\begin{align*}
\min(a,b+c)&\leq \min(a,b)+\min(a,c)\\
a &\leq a+a=2a
\end{align*}
Case 2: if $\,\,b\leq a\leq c\,\,$ and $\,\,c\leq a \leq b,\,\,$ we have
\begin{align*}
\min(a,b+c)&\leq \min(a,b)+\min(a,c)\\
a &\leq b+a
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\min(a,b+c)&\leq \min(a,b)+\min(a,c)\\
a &\leq a+c
\end{align*}
Case 3: $\,\,c\leq b\leq a\,\,$ and $\,\,b\leq c \leq a,\,\,$ 
I am not sure about this case, because although $a$ is the biggest from $b$ and $c$, it can satisfies $a\leq b+c$ or $b+c\leq a$. Is the third case must be done with two cases again? i.e for $a\leq b+c$ and $b+c\leq a$?

or there is another way to prove $\min(a,b+c)\leq \min(a,b)+ \min(a,c)$ for $a,b,c\geq 0$?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative proof:

**Case 1:** $a\ge b+c.$ Then $a\ge b, a\ge c$. $$\min(a,b+c)=b+c =\min(a,b)+ c=\min(a,b)+\min(a,c).$$

**Case 2:** $a \le b+c.$ Then $\exists x, y \ge 0, a=x+y$, such that $x\le b, y \le c$. (For example $x=\frac{ab}{b+c}, y=\frac{ac}{b+c}.)$

Then
$$ x \le a, x \le b \implies x \le \min(a,b)$$
$$ y \le a, y \le c \implies y \le \min(a,c)$$
Therefore
$$
a=x+y \le \min(a,b)+\min(a,c). \blacksquare
$$

Answer (score 3):

For your case 3: $\min\{a,b\} + \min\{a,c\}  = b+c$. Since $\min\{a,b+c\}\leq b+c$ (min is always less than both numbers) you get the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

There's another way. Consider the function $f(a)=\min(a,b)+\min(a,c)-\min(a,b+c)$. It's piece-wise linear, so to prove it's non-negative, we only need to check its value at each endpoint of the intervals (including $+\infty$):

$f(0)=0+0-0=0;$

$f(b)=b+\min(b,c)-\min(b,b+c)=\min(b,c) \ge 0.$

By symmetry $f(c)=\min(b,c)$.

$f(b+c)=b+c-(b+c)=0.$

And lastly, when $a\to \infty, f(a)=b+c-(b+c)=0.$

---

Some other problems can be solved this way as well:

[Show $\frac{1}{\lvert a - b \rvert} < \frac{2}{\lvert a \rvert}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923618/show-frac1-lvert-a-b-rvert-frac2-lvert-a-rvert) : This one you just check the function $f(b)=2|a-b|-|a|$ at $b=\frac{|a|}{2} - \varepsilon, -\frac{|a|}{2}+ \varepsilon$, with $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrarily small.

[Prove that $|a|\leq \max\{|b|,|c|\}$ if $b\leq a \leq c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3918165/prove-that-a-leq-max-b-c-if-b-leq-a-leq-c) : This one you check $a=0, b, c$ (even though $0$ may be outside of $[b,c]$).

Even equations: [Why does the equality $\max\{a,\min\{b,c\}\}=\min\{\max\{a,b\},\max\{a,c\}\}$ hold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944748/why-does-the-equality-max-a-min-b-c-min-max-a-b-max-a-c-ho) where you check $a=\min(b,c), b,c, -\infty, +\infty$.

Or even this one [Reverse Triangle Inequality Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof) albeit not the best way.